# What would an inhabitable world for a very long term immortal be?

Tags: evolution, environment, immortality

I've seen a a lots of topics about short/mid term immortality, but I'm interested in very long term immortality in the range of millions of years.

The immortal character, a Homo Sapiens, has slowly witnessed the evolution of Humanity to a new species. He's the only one occurrence of immortality.

Post-Humanity accepts him, just like we would accept an immortal Australopithecus living among us doing his business. Post-Humanity has gathered enough knowledge about him over millions of years so there's no curiosity about him, everything that has to be known about him is known, so Post-People leave him be, no one cares about him any more.

Now, this immortal, that lived this last millions of years a retreated and peaceful life, starts to realize that the environmental conditions that made Homo Sapiens evolve are going to be unbearable for him in the next millions of years. One day, he faces the eventuality of living an endless circle of agony/death/resurrection/very-short-life/agony/death/resurrection...

He has a few millions of years to build *his* world so environmental conditions don't constantly kill him. What does he need to consider? How would *his* ideal world be and how could he achieve it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. If, other than being immortal, he's just a normal human being, then the answer to what environmental conditions he needs is surely just normal earth-like conditions.

Comment: "Post-Humanity accepts him, just like we would accept an immortal Australopithecus living among us doing his business" While that might be true in an area or two, it's unlikely to be true universally on our world today. It's a nice thought, though (as is the idea that millions of years from now we don't still choose to hate).

Comment: I was also the last close voter. Let me tell you why. You didn't explain to us what your immortal needs to persistently rejuvenate. One could assume that the Earth 20,000 years ago would be pretty much perfect, but you don't say. Worse, you're apparently asking for an explanation of how to terraform a planet? We "kinda" know how to do that, but having never done it, you're asking for a lot. If that's what you're asking for.

Answer (score 1):

Well it has to do with the geology around him or climate in the area he lives. If he lives in a tropical area and plants start dying, he start replanting new seeds or trees that can survive that climate or weather.